# How to share google gmail api authentication from client to node server

Tags: node.js, gmail-api

I have a nodeserver serving two routes

1. / = https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js
2. /json/ = {mydata: 'abc'};

**node-server.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', ['src/views']);

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
});

app.get('/json', (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  // if authenticated
  res.end(JSON.stringify({mydata: 'abc'}));
  // else 
  res.end(JSON.stringify({auth: false}));
});
```

**src/views/index.ejs** === (browser example) https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js

**Question**

After a user has authenticated via browser method, how can I share authenticated state with my nodeserver so that I only show json data if authenticated, otherwise an error?

Answer (score 0):

ok I think it is not possible to access the token if created via the browser. Unless somone else can chip in with a solution.

Meanwhile I have created an alternative to the browser example provided by google quickstart but in node. That way I have control of the access_token from node server and can determine if user is signed in or not.

My solution:

**Pre-requisites**

- Must have created a google workspace with a - first project
- Must have created a client id and api key -  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js
- Must downloaded the credentials.json file and keep local to nodeserver for use.
- Must have supplied: [link OAuthClient Client] > Credentials] Authorised redirect URIs
  http://localhost:8000/oauth2callback
- This is a typescript implementation so will need cross-env or equivalent to transpile with babel wile running from package.json script.

**nodeServer.ts**

```js
import yargs from 'yargs';
import express, { Response } from 'express';
import path from 'path';

import fs from 'fs';
import { google, Auth } from 'googleapis';
import url from 'url';
import { gmail_v1 } from 'googleapis/build/src/apis/gmail/v1';

type OAuth2Client = Auth.OAuth2Client;
interface Icredentials {
  web: {
    client_id: string;
    project_id: string;
    auth_uri: string;
    token_uri: string;
    auth_provider_x509_cert_url: string;
    client_secret: string;
    redirect_uris: string;
  };
}

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];
const pathCredentials = path.resolve(__dirname, '../credentials/credentials-webserver.json');
const contentCredentials: string = fs.readFileSync(pathCredentials, 'utf8');
const credentials: Icredentials = JSON.parse(contentCredentials);
const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials.web;

const oAuth2Client: OAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  client_id,
  client_secret,
  redirect_uris[0]
);

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', ['src/views']);

const { argv } = yargs;
const port = argv.port || 8000;
const host = argv.host || 'localhost';

const pathRoot = path.join(__dirname, '/');

type TgetSignedIn = (oAuth2Client: OAuth2Client) => Promise<boolean>;
const getSignedIn: TgetSignedIn = oAuth2Client =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!oAuth2Client.credentials.access_token) {
      reject(Error('access_token does not exist'))
    } else {
      resolve(true);
    }
  });

type TgetLabels = (
  auth: OAuth2Client
) => Promise<gmail_v1.Schema$ListLabelsResponse | gmail_v1.Schema$Label[]>;
const getLabels: TgetLabels = auth => {
  const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth });
  return gmail.users.labels.list({ userId: 'me' }).then(
    res =>
      // res.config.Authorization: 'Bearer Accesstoken....'
      res.data.labels
  );
};

type TrenderLabels = (res: Response, isSignedIn: boolean) => void;
const renderLabels: TrenderLabels = (res, isSignedIn) => {
  getLabels(oAuth2Client)
    .then(labels => {
      res.render('index', { labels, isSignedIn });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.render('index', { isSignedIn });
    });
};

app.use('/', express.static(pathRoot));

app.get('/', (req, res) =>
  getSignedIn(oAuth2Client)
    .then(() => {
      renderLabels(res, true);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      res.render('index', { isSignedIn: false });
    })
);

app.get('/getAuthCode', (req, res) => {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  res.render('index', { authUrl, isSignedIn: false });
});

app.get('/oauth2callback', (req, res) => {
  const qs = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
  const { code } = qs;
  if (!code) {
    return console.error('Error - unselected email');
  }
  const decodedCode = decodeURIComponent(code as string);
  oAuth2Client.getToken(decodedCode, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
    renderLabels(res, true);
  });
});

app.get('/signout', (req, res) => {
  delete oAuth2Client.credentials.access_token;
  res.render('index', { isSignedIn: false });
});

app.get('/services', (req, res) => {
  getSignedIn(oAuth2Client)
    .then(() => {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.end(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.end(JSON.stringify({ error: err, custom: 'You are signed out!' }));
    });
});

app.listen(port, host, () => {
  // console.log('listening on ', host, ':', port);
});
```

**index.ejs**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Gmail API Quickstart</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <% if (typeof authUrl !== 'undefined') { %>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0 url=<%= authUrl %>" />
  <% } %>

</head>

<body>
  <p>Gmail API Quickstart</p>
  <button id="authorize_button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
  <button id="signout_button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>
  
  <% if (typeof labels !== 'undefined') { %> 
    <ul>
      <% labels.forEach(item => { %>
        <li><%= item.name %></li>
      <% }) %>
    </ul>
  <% } %>

  <script>
    const handleAuthClick = () => {
      location.href = '/getAuthCode';
    };
    const handleSignout = () => {
      location.href = '/signout';
    };
    const init = (isSignedIn) => {
      var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize_button');
      authorizeButton.style.display = isSignedIn ? 'none' : 'block';
      authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;

      var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout_button');
      signoutButton.style.display = isSignedIn ? 'block' : 'none';
      signoutButton.onclick = handleSignout;
    }
    init(<%= isSignedIn %>);

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This provides me the following paths:

1. It creates a similar experience as this: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js
2. Now when user goes to /services/ path I display json if logged in or error if not.

Also if anyone has a better suggestion that just removing the access_token manually to detect if user is signed in, please advise.